# MYSQL - INCLUDE DATES w. 0 Records in New Users Query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( user_id ) AS `Records` , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `since` ) ) AS `Date`
FROM `users` WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(since) >= '2014-11-00'
GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `since` ) )
LIMIT 200
```

This query returns new signups per day , but it leaves big gaps in the chart for dates where there are 0 new signups, how can I get it to includes these dates w. a 0 for the count?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of dates, and use a LEFT or RIGHT Join.

Have a look at the JOINs here : [Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Not getting how thats going to make dates with no records appear and idt creating a table that creates a record for each date just for the sake of this , that just sounds sloppy.